# Use Design Automation for revit with an IFC input file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Is it possible to run a Design Automation addin for Revit with an IFC as input file?
The idea is to send only an Ifc file and run the addin that must convert it to rvt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demonstrated by the [IfcSpaceZoneBoundaries](https://github.com/jeremytammik/IfcSpaceZoneBoundaries) add-in.

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Design Automation for Revit supports Open IFC. You can try this API: `Application.OpenIFCDocument Method (String)`.

Follow the [tutorials](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/) on how to run a Revit add-in in Design Automation. You can also find [some code samples](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-createfamily-revit).

In this particular question on how to open IFC file in Design Automation. You should not provide the IFC file as `/i` argument in the commandLine, e.g. "commandLine": [ "$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe  /al "$(appbundles[< your appbundle >].path)"" ]. In this way, no input will be opened automatically and your addin can call `OpenIFCDocument` to open IFC file which is downloaded as one of inputs.

Comment: Hi, I have the same question "how to open IFC in DESIGN AUTOMATION". I downvote this answer until you could provide a bit more details as I'm unable to open IFC in DA based on such thin code snippet. I basically don't see where/how I have the opportunity to invoke OpenIFCDocument as the input document in DA is already getting open automatically and my code is being provided with DesignAutomationData object. I'm getting InvalidOperationException exception at Application.OpenDocumentFile which isn't invoked by custom code. Please take time to do proper support, thanks.

Comment: You should not provide `/i` in the commandLine, you can define the commandLine, e.g. `"commandLine": [ "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe  /al \"$(appbundles[<your appbundle>].path)\"" ]`. In this way, no input will be opened automatically and your addin can call `OpenIFCDocument` to open IFC file which is downloaded as one of inputs.

Comment: BTW, you could also send questions to `forge.help@autodesk.com` directly so you may get a reply quicker from the support team sometimes. (I am a developer, not from the support team, so I may delay catching the questions and reply to them.) thanks.

Comment: Ok that's one step further, you would need to edit your answer so I can upvote it. It's still not really enough information to be able to completely sort it out by myself as it's unclear how to exactly initialize the DA code but i guess I will have to dig out all the pieces myself. Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer by providing links for tutorials and code samples too. Hope they help.